# Garbage Collection doesn't remove local variable

Tags: javafx, garbage-collection, ram

There is a messege about waiting for updates, when my programm is starting. This messege is showed in a separate method. So, everything inside this method should be removed by Garbage Collector. But Profiler (I use NetBeans 8.1) shows me, that all objects, connected with a Label from separate method, still exist (javax.swing objects). How can I remove all objects connected with the Label and the Label itself for cleaning a memmory (RAM)?

These unnecessary objects, for example:
javax.swing.text.GapContent, javax.swing.text.html.parser.Parser and all other objects from package javax.swing

```
package example;  

import java.io.IOException;  
import javafx.application.Application;  
import javafx.scene.Scene;  
import javafx.scene.control.Button;  
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;  
import javafx.stage.Stage;  

public class Example extends Application {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
    launch(args);  
}  

    @Override  
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {  
        showMsgCheckUpdate();  
        System.gc();  
        StackPane root = new StackPane();  
        root.getChildren().add(new Button("Say 'Hello World'"));  

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);  

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");  
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);  
        primaryStage.show();  
    }  

    private void showMsgCheckUpdate() throws IOException {  
        java.awt.Dimension size = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();  
        javax.swing.JWindow message = new javax.swing.JWindow();  
        javax.swing.JLabel l = new javax.swing.JLabel("<html><H1>Идет проверка наличия обновлений...</html>");  
        message.add(l);  
        message.setOpacity(0.9f);  
        message.pack();  
        message.setBounds(size.width / 2 - message.getWidth() / 2, size.height / 2 - message.getHeight() / 2, message.getWidth(), message.getHeight());  
        message.setVisible(true);  
        // Тут проверка обновления  
        message.setVisible(false);  
        message.dispose();  
    }  
}
```

There is a Profiler's screenshot: http://fastpic.ru/view/73/2016/0401/0aa1bc957c73dd026ce5add133f1da5c.png.html

We have the same situation with a Stage when we use javafx.

```
private void showMsgCheckUpdate() throws IOException {  
    Label l = new Label("Идет проверка наличия обновлений...");  

    Stage stage = new Stage();  
    Scene scene = new Scene(l);  
    scene.getStylesheets().add("");  

    stage.setScene(scene);  
    stage.show();  
    // Тут проверка обновления  
    stage.close();  
}
```

There is a Profiler's screenshot: http://fastpic.ru/view/76/2016/0401/80a3297ac660458a0feb327f74e18b01.png.html

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection is not easy to predict and I wouldn't relay on the fact that some object will or will not be removed.

Why would you like to force those object to be removed from the heap?

Comment: I need to clean my memory, coz this app eats too much, and these is one of the problems - alive objects after their deleting.

Comment: @Tereshka There is no way to force garbage collector to remove those objects. It will remove them when there is not enough memory in the young or old generation (and the object is not used, so just as in your case). Did you try to see the list of objects after the minor of full GC?

Comment: @Tereshka Also calling System.gc() is pointless, java will call GC when it needs to, not when we force it to.

Comment: I have Object1 (Label), which u can see in my example, it is created at the beginning of my programm. While the programm is working, Object2 is created (it doesn't show in this example). After it's using  Object2 is destroyed. In Profiler I can see, how Object2 appears, works, and then is destroyed and disappeared from Profiler. As Object2 was destroyed, I make desicion, that GC works. But Object1 after Object2's destoying still exists. So GC can't remove Object1, because it is used by some connections/references. And my question: how can I find and remove any references that use Object1?

Comment: Profiler's stack u can see on screenshots in the first post.